# What type of heirlooms are worn by which classes?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So there are **4** armor types:

1. Cloth
2. Leather
3. Mail
4. Plate

I want to know which heirloom types (type of armor) goes to which classes? A list sort of format would be useful.

Also, **Paladins and Warriors can wear Plate, but only from Level 40**. Up to that point they wear Mail. Can they receive and wear Plate heirlooms from the get go (Level 1) or should I rather get them Mail heirlooms?

Comment: It's strange that Warcraft doesn't specify this, whereas in Diablo, almost everything is class-specific...

Answer (score 9):

You can basically just buy the heirlooms that have useful stats for your class. A thing to note:

**Mail with Agility/Intellect and Plate with Strength/Intellect will change the armor type pre level 40**

This means for Hunters and Shamans you can buy the [Agility-Mail](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=1751/heirloom-list#am) for example. They are Leather under level 40 and turn into Mail automatically once you reach level 40 with your character. (If you send it to another character that's lower than 40 you will get leather again). This of course works the same for Plate wearers.

Heirloom armors like the [Agility-Leather](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=1751/heirloom-list#al) however will not turn into mail after level 40.

You also have to know that the main reason why you actually buy heirlooms is not the fact that they scale with level, but rather for the Percentage bonus experience. This means you can also buy a Agility-Leather armor on Hunters or shamans for example. While you can also play with Cloth-Intellect on a warrior during the first few levels if you don't have the plate set, you should definitely switch to normal armor after around level 20 since it would take you too long to kill NPCs after this point.

Comment: A single odd piece of equip won't matter, you can just use cloth anyway.

Comment: The fact that most heirlooms are BiS until way into outland helps as well. It's not only about the xp gain. Ever tried low level pvp with a full heirloom hunter or warrior? It's fun :P

Comment: @Lohoris Well, a single piece might cost you your 5% specialization bonus after level 50. So considering you're down a major slot AND the specialization you could be down as much as 10% output for that single piece.

Comment: @corsiKa leveling is easy anyway, and optimising the character while leveling is pointless. This kind of argument only works when you talk about endgame, everywhere else it's moot.

Comment: @Kevin you're right, I didn't take PvP into account. Yes, if you do PvP at low levels, then it matters. When talking about WoW I assume PvE unless otherwise specified. (because technically it _is_ a PvE game where PvP has been violently hacked into)

Comment: Another nice thing about heirlooms is that with enchantments scaling now, you can do things like put current endgame enchants (e.g., Dancing Steel) on that gear and get some very good benefits the entire time you're leveling.  I wouldn't bother enchanting every piece, but weapons and say chest and/or legs give some great bonuses.

Comment: @Lohoris Optimizing the character is hardly pointless. 10% is 10%. If a typical 90 takes 4 days played, that's nearly 10 hours saved. 10 hours of my time isn't pointless.

Comment: @corsiKa if you're having fun they they aren't hours wasted, but I see your point.

Answer (score 6):

There are eight sets of heirloom armour. Since patch 6.2, there is at least one set for each spec.

- [Tattered Dreadmist](http://www.wowhead.com/list=3609355): Spellcasting Cloth.

  > Best for Priests, Mages, Warlocks.
  >
  > Suboptimal for Balance Druids, Elemental Shamans, Holy Paladins.
- [Preened Feathers](http://www.wowhead.com/list=3609874): Spellcasting Leather.

  > Best for Balance Druids, Restoration Druids, Mistweaver Monks.
  >
  > Suboptimal for Elemental Shamans, Holy Paladins.
- [Stained Shadowcraft](http://www.wowhead.com/list=3610710): Agility Leather.

  > Best for Rogues, Feral Druids, Guardian Druids, Brewmaster Monks, Windwalker Monks.
  >
  > Suboptimal for Enhancement Shamans, Hunters.
- [Mystical Elements](http://www.wowhead.com/list=3610740)<sup>2</sup>: Spellcasting Mail.

  > Best for Elemental Shamans, Restoration Shamans.
  >
  > Suboptimal for Holy Paladins.
- [Hunter Loot](http://www.wowhead.com/list=3610764)<sup>2 4</sup>: Agility Mail.

  > Best for Enhancement Shamans, Hunters.
- [Burnished Might](http://www.wowhead.com/list=3611438)<sup>3</sup>: Tanking Plate.

  > Best for Protection Warriors, Protection Paladins, Blood Death Knights.
- [Polished Valor](http://www.wowhead.com/list=3611352)<sup>3</sup>: Strength Plate.

  > Best for Fury Warriors, Arms Warriors, Retribution Paladins, Frost Death Knights, Unholy Death Knights.
- [Pristine Lightforge](http://www.wowhead.com/list=7685550): Intellect Plate. Added in patch 6.2

  > Best for Holy Paladins

---

<sup>1. <s>Holy Paladins do not have their own heirloom set.</s> No longer true as of patch 6.2</sup>
<sup>2. Will become leather for Shamans and Hunters below level 40.</sup>
<sup>3. Will become mail for Paladins and Warriors below level 40.</sup>
<sup>4. There is no single name for this heirloom set. The name refers to the tendency of Hunters to use Strength mail items simply because they can use it, as evidenced by the Raging Berserker's Helm and Herod's Shoulder.</sup>

Comment: As of 6.2, Holy Paladins have the Pristine Lightforge heirloom set. I'll edit the answer when I have time

Answer (score 3):

After quite a bit of research I have found that sending Plate heirlooms off to a Paladin or Warrior will change them to Mail until the character can wear Plate, then it will be converted back to Plate. This only applies to this scenario, and for Mail for Hunters and Shamans.

Below is a list of Classes by armor type (the heirlooms work the same):

#### Plate:

1. Death Knight
2. Paladin
3. Warrior

#### Mail:

1. Hunter
2. Shaman

#### Leather:

1. Druid
2. Monk
3. Rogue

#### Cloth:

1. Mage
2. Priest
3. Warlock